# Azure VM: Why do I only have an option for Windows Server 2016 Data Center

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, development-environment

Very Simple question. Not new to Azure, but new to setting up environments.  Im trying to setup a simple DEV env and I don't need Data Center.  Why do I only have an option for Windows 2016 data center and not just a regular Windows 2016 server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Server 2016 Standard edition image is currently not available in Azure Marketplace. You can, however, procure a Windows Server 2016 Standard image and upload it to Azure in the form of a VHD. Then, you can spin up a VM with that OS.

Refer [Create a Windows VM from a specialized disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized)